# Are there differences between [...array].map(...) and [...array.map(...)] in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can't quite understand the differences between `[...array].map(...)` and `[...array.map(...)]`. Are they any different? If yes, why and how?

Comment: Have you tried these 2? What differences did you notice?

Comment: Or just `array.map(...)` which does the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `[...array].map(...)` will generate a new shallow copy of an array (`[...array]`) and then `.map` over it and return a brand new array as the return value.
- `[...array.map(...)]` will `.map` over the original array, which will return a new array, and then immediately make a shallow copy of the new array (`[...array.map(...)]`).  I must admit, I don't really understand the use case for this approach-- because `.map` itself is returning a brand new array that no other variable should be holding a reference to, I don't see any value in immediately casting a shallow copy of it.

(Also, as pointed out by [chazsolo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4095444/chazsolo) in the comments, if `array` were *not* an array, but in fact some other type like a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set), the `[...array.map(...)]` approach would actually throw an error, as `Set` instances have no `.map` method).

Comment: I'd mention that `array` could be an Iterable, like a Set. The first case would work as expected, the second would throw a TypeError.

Comment: @chazsolo -- good call out-- updated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Well `[...array.map(...)]` is the same as `array.map(...)` except that it does an extra unnecessary spread/copy after the mapping is done.

The `[...array].map(...)` has an small difference, due to the 3rd parameter passed in map (*the array it self*).

And as mentioned in another comment, by @chazsolo, this case will handle cases where the `array` variable is not an array, so it does not have the `map` method, but can be iterated and the spread will create an array out of it.